# SMS encryption gives exception while decrypting

Tags: android, sms, encryption

I am developing an android application that deals with the SMS.
I am done with the app but one last thing remains unsolved: the encryption.

How can I work that out to encrypt the incoming SMS?

```
public class enc {

        private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
        private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
        private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
        private Cipher cipher;

        private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";

        public enc()
        {
            ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

            keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

            try {
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String encrypt(String text) throws Exception
        {
            if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
                throw new Exception("Empty string");

            byte[] encrypted = null;

            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

                encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e)
            {           
                throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
            }
            String s = new String(encrypted);
            Log.v("TAG", s);


            return s;
        }

        public String decrypt(String code) throws Exception
        {
            if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
                throw new Exception("Empty string");

            byte[] decrypted = null;

            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

                decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.v("TAG", decrypted.toString());
            String s = new String(decrypted);
            Log.v("TAG", s);
            return s;
        }



        public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int len = data.length;
            String str = "";
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                    str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                else
                    str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
            return str;
        }


        public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
            if (str==null) {
                return null;
            } else if (str.length() < 2) {
                return null;
            } else {
                int len = str.length() / 2;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                    buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
                }
                return buffer;
            }
        }



        private static String padString(String source)
        {
          char paddingChar = ' ';
          int size = 16;
          int x = source.length() % size;
          int padLength = size - x;

          for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
          {
              source += paddingChar;
          }

          return source;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this, but it gives an exception when decrypting, that it can't parse the "A character".
By a character I mean an alphabet like a, b, c is shown, that can't be parsed.

Any help?

```
04-24 13:56:17.191: V/(2031): Message Recieved
04-24 13:56:22.811: V/TAG(2031): [B@44ebb318
04-24 13:56:22.811: V/Encrypted(2031): [B@44ebb318
04-24 13:56:22.931: W/System.err(2031): java.lang.Exception: [decrypt] unable to parse '[B' as integer
04-24 13:56:22.941: W/System.err(2031):     at sms.app.enc.decrypt(enc.java:86)
04-24 13:56:22.951: W/System.err(2031):     at sms.app.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:86)
04-24 13:56:22.961: W/System.err(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
04-24 13:56:22.961: W/System.err(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-24 13:56:22.970: W/System.err(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
04-24 13:56:22.981: W/System.err(2031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 13:56:22.981: W/System.err(2031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 13:56:22.991: W/System.err(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 13:56:23.001: W/System.err(2031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 13:56:23.001: W/System.err(2031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 13:56:23.011: W/System.err(2031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 13:56:23.021: W/System.err(2031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 13:56:23.021: W/System.err(2031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to better understand the difference between Java characters and bytes, as your code reveals fundamental misunderstandings. It doesn't make sense and probably won't work to construct a String from the output of encryption. Also, your use of `toString()` doesn't make sense for a `byte[]` array.

Comment: @GregS if i dont even use the toString method and work with the byte array itt still gives the same exception

Comment: I appreciate that but my point is that you need get more comfortable with the differences between characters and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post the full stack trace. As it stands there are three problems with your code:

- your key is weak: you should just construct a key from some ASCII characters. That severely limits the key space and makes it easy to brute force the key
- don't use non-standard padding. Use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")` to get proper padding
- don't use a fixed IV, generate a random one for each encryption operation

Additionally, using `getBytes()` might give weird results, since the encoding is undefined (uses platform default). It will probably be consistent on Android, but use `getBytes("UTF-8")` to make sure you get the same bytes from the same string.

Comment: upated with the logcat please check it out

Comment: Check your inputs and outputs. Your encryption code seems to try to convert encrypted (~random bytes) to a String, while the decryption code seems to expect a hex-encoded string. (Mostly what @GregS said)